# What is the number of configurations for three cups and three cubes?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

You have three cups and three cubes. The cubes are put into the cups.

In how many different ways can these be arranged if the cubes must all go in the cups?

For example, one possibly arrangement is all the cubes in one of the cups (there are 3 ways to do this one). Another is one cube in each cup (there are 6 ways to do this one).

The order that the cubes go in the cups doesn't matter, but the cup each cube goes into does matter.

How many different ways can these be arranged?

Comment: $3^3$? For each cube, pick one cup to put it in?

Comment: @rushabh-mehta, the cubes can't be repeated and the cups can also be empty. I'm not sure this accounts for those cases.

Comment: What do you mean the cubes can't be repeated? This accounts for the cups being empty.

Comment: @rushabh-mehta, I see what you mean now, that's much simpler than what I was thinking. I was looking at it from the perspective of what cubes to pick for the cups, not what cups to pick for the cubes.

Comment: Are the cubes identical?  Are the cups identical.  @RushabhMehta solution is correct if we can tell cups and cubes apart.

Comment: @DougM, the cups are labelled and so are the cubes, meaning they are NOT identical.

Comment: @DougM I assumed they were distinguishable by how OP counted cases in his/her attempt